# Different values in array

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm using Java, I'm trying to get all the different values from 2d array with recursive function only and without use HashSet ArrayList etc..,
The values will be only [0-9]
i.e:

```
{{4,2,2,1,4},{4,4,3,1,4},{1,1,4,2,1},{1,4,0,2,2},{4,1,4,1,1}}; -> Returns 5 (Because 4,2,3,1,0)
{{4,6,2,1,4},{4,4,3,1,4},{1,1,4,2,1},{1,4,0,2,2},{4,1,4,1,1}}; -> Returns 6 (Because 4,2,3,1,0,6)
{{4,4,4,4,4}}; -> Returns 1 (4)
```

What I tried:

```
public static int numOfColors(int[][] map) {
    int colors = 0;
    if (map == null || map.length == 0) {
        return colors;
    } else {
        int[] subArr = map[map.length - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < subArr.length; i++) {
            int j = i + 1;
            for (; j < subArr.length; j++) {
                if (subArr[i] == subArr[j]) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == subArr.length) {
                int k = 0;
                for (; k < map.length - 1; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < map[k].length; l++) {
                        if (subArr[i] == map[k][l]) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (k == map.length - 1) {
                    colors++;
                }
            }
        }
        int[][] dest = new int[map.length - 1][];
        System.arraycopy(map, 0, dest, 0, map.length - 1);
        colors += numOfColors(dest);

        return colors;
    }
}
```

But this hasn't worked for me, where is the miskate?

Comment: Why use recursion?

Comment: You need some kind of storage to know if you have seen the values before, or delete all instants of a value after you count them, so sum up the colors for each sub-arrays won't work. Also, recursion seems a strange choice here since it doesn't simplify the problem nor make the solution more efficient

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Note: the values will be only {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already mentioned by @Cash Lo, you need some kind of storage. So you algorithm could looks something like:

```
@Test
public void numOfColorsTest() {
    int[][] map = new int[][] {{4,2,2,1,4},{4,4,3,1,4},{1,1,4,2,1},{1,4,0,2,2},{4,1,4,1,1}};
    System.out.println(String.format("numOfColors: %s", numOfColors(map, new int[0], map.length-1)));

    map = new int[][] {{4,6,2,1,4},{4,4,3,1,4},{1,1,4,2,1},{1,4,0,2,2},{4,1,4,1,1}};
    System.out.println(String.format("numOfColors: %s", numOfColors(map, new int[0], map.length-1)));

    map = new int[][] {{4,4,4,4,4}};
    System.out.println(String.format("numOfColors: %s", numOfColors(map, new int[0], map.length-1)));
}

public static int numOfColors(int[][] map, int[] collector, int currentPosition) {
    int[] result = collector;
    if (currentPosition < 0) {
        return collector.length;
    }
    for (int color : map[currentPosition]) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int aResult : result) {
            if (aResult == color) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            int[] newResult = new int[result.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(result, 0, newResult, 0, result.length);
            newResult[newResult.length - 1] = color;
            result = newResult;
        }
    }
    return numOfColors(map, result, currentPosition-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursion doesn't make much sense here. Just use a simple array as storage, and count the instances of different values, if you know the range (0-9) then a simple int[] will be sufficient.

This should do the trick:

```
public static int numOfColors(int[][] map){

    int[] storage = new int[10];

    //iterate through all the values
    for(int i = 0; i<map.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<map[0].length; j++){

            //will throw an Exception if an entry in map is not 0-9
            //you might want to check for that
            storage[map[i][j]]++;

        }
    }

    int colors = 0;
    //now check which values exist.
    for(int i = 0; i<storage.length; i++){
        if(storage[i] != 0) colors++;
    }

    return colors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not the answer but you should always think if your solution makes sense.

In my opinion using recursion here is very bad idea because:

- the code isn't readable at all
- I haven't checked that but I doubt it's more efficient
- recursion is hard to debug
- you're making really simple problem complicated

Consider the following code. It does exactly what you need:

```
Integer[][] array = {{4,2,2,1,4},{4,4,3,1,4},{1,1,4,2,1},{1,4,0,2,2},{4,1,4,1,1}};
int size = Arrays.stream(array)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        .size();
System.out.println("size = " + size);
```

If you purposely use recursion in this case the only thing I can recommend is Test Driven Development. Write the algorithm and tests simultaneously.